# Is it safe to compare floats strictly, given we do no operations on them?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

Normally, when we want to test fractional numbers for equality, we do so with some amount of uncertainty, because of approximate nature of IEEE754.

```
if (fabs(one_float - other_float) < SUFFICIENTLY_SMALL) {
    consider them equal;
}
```

Other approach might be to cast the floats to integers of specific magnitude, and compare resulting integers instead.

```
if ((uint)one_float == (uint)other_float) {
    consider them equal;
}
```

But consider the situation where our floats never undergo any arithmetics, and the only thing we do with them is assignment.

```
//  Might be called at any moment
void resize(float new_width, float new_height)
{
    if (current_width == new_width && current_height == new_height) {
        return;
    }

    accomodate framebuffers;
    update uniforms;
    do stuff;

    current_width = new_width;
    current_height = new_height;
}
```

In the example above, we have an event handler that may fire up spontaneously, and we want to reallocate resources only if real resize occurred. We might take the usual path with approximate comparison, but that seems like a waste, because that handler will fire up pretty often. As far as I know, floats are assigned just as everything else, using memory move; and equality operator performs just the memory comparison. So it looks like we are in a safe harbour. When checked on x86 and ARM, this assumption holds, but I just wanted to be sure. Maybe it's backed by some specs?

So, is there something that might change floats when only assigning them? Is the described approach viable?

Comment: Yes, *at the moment you assign them*. The value you specify may not be accurately represented, so the value has already changed.

Comment: It might be OK on some machines but it is still risky. It may work differently on different machines.

Comment: The new sizes comes from somewhere, how do you know there is no small error in representartion? *Never check floating point for equality*.

Comment: "As far as I know, floats are assigned just as everything else, using memory move; and equality operator performs just the memory comparison". This is not true for NaN values. [Merely loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050133/are-the-bit-patterns-of-nans-really-hardware-dependent#comment38981088_25051746) certain NaN values into FP registers can cause them to change into different NaNs. And NaNs compare as inequal to themselves. There is also special handling for zero, as positive zero compares as equal to negative zero, although they have different bit patterns.

Comment: There is a typo in your second equality operator in the if clause; should be "==".

Comment: @Boann, I did not know that loading could affect actual bits. Is that true for any float value or only for NaNs?

Comment: "equality operator performs just the memory comparison" must have overlooked this. My Clang still generates `ucomiss`. Perhaps I should correct the wording.

Comment: @PopEye I'm fairly sure it can only happen for NaNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mass of "should"s follows.

I don't think there's anything that says an assignment from float to float (`current_width = new_width`) couldn't alter the value, but I would be surprised if such a thing existed. There should be no reason to make assignment between variables of the same type anything else than a direct copy.

If the incoming `new_width` and `new_height` keep their values until they change, then this comparison should not have any issues. But if they are calculated before every call they might change their value, depending on how the calculation is done. So it's not only this function that needs to be checked.

The C 2011 standard says that calculations may use bigger precision than the format you assign to, but nothing specific about assigning a variable to another. So the only imprecision *should* be in the calculation stage. The "simple assignment" part (6.5.16.1) says:

> In simple  assignment (=),  the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  converted  to  the  type  of  the assignment  expression  and  replaces  the  value  stored  in  the  object  designated  by  the  left operand.

So if the types already match, there should be no need for conversion.

So, simply put: if you don't recalculate the incoming value on every call the comparison for equality *should* hold true. But is there really a case where your framebuffers are sized as floats and not integers?

Comment: Good points. So, if I understand correctly, it is only safe if we trust the upstream framework to supply us bitwise equivalents each time. We also have to be sure that we do not load our values to fp registers for comparison. As for me, that pretty much build up to use the usual comparison method. Sigh.

Comment: Regarding float framebuffers. Yes, they are int-sized, yet those floats are supplied by the environment in the event object.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you mentioned it is safe to use `==` to compare because of the following lines at the end of the function:

```
current_width = new_width;
current_height = new_height;
```

any change to `new_width` or `new_height` will fail the if statement and you get the behavior you wanted.

`abs()` function usually is used when there is one variable float which is assigned dynamically in the program and one constant float which you want to use as a reference. Something like:

```
bool isEqual(float first, float second)
{
   if(fabs(first-second)<0.0001)
      return true;
   return false;
}

int main()
{
   float x = (float) 1 / 3;
   if(isEqual(x,0.3333))
      printf("It is equal\n");
   else
      printf("It is not equal\n");
}
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that `0.3333` is `double` not `float`, so there is another conversion happening which will result in more loss of precision.

Comment: @WeatherVane that is correct and that's why abs function is needed to check that, with a tweak on the precision to reach the desired functionality

Comment: No, that is not why `abs` is needed. In any case it should be `fabs`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I used `abs` because it is a pseudocode. Fixed anyway not to confuse anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here for how to compare two floats.

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Find the test with "ULP, he said nervously". You can compare the floats as ints but have a look at how it's been done in the article ie (I hope I'm not breaching any licensing here, if so please delete the code that follows it's not mine)

```
bool AlmostEqualUlps(float A, float B, int maxUlpsDiff){
    Float_t uA(A);
    Float_t uB(B);
    // Different signs means they do not match.
    if (uA.Negative() != uB.Negative()) {
        // Check for equality to make sure +0==-0
        if (A == B) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Find the difference in ULPs.
    int ulpsDiff = abs(uA.i - uB.i);
    if (ulpsDiff <= maxUlpsDiff) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please read the rest of that  article, it's really good.

Comment: "Different signs means they do not match" is untrue. They may both be very close to, but not exactly 0, with different sign. Checking the absolute difference works here: there is no special case.