# If the next representable value after -0.0 is +0.0, then why nextafter(-0.0, INFINITY) does not return +0.0?

Tags: c, floating-point, c11, math.h, c17

If the next representable value after `-0.0` is `+0.0`, then why `nextafter(-0.0, INFINITY)` does not return `+0.0`?

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Why should it? I don't see the logic.

Comment: Essentially, I would suggest that `-0.0` and `+0.0` represent the *same* value. From cppreference: *IEC 60559 recommends that from is returned whenever from==to. These functions return to instead, which makes the behavior around zero consistent: std::nextafter(-0.0, +0.0) returns +0.0 and std::nextafter(+0.0, -0.0) returns -0.0.*

Comment: @AdrianMole You should write that as an answer

Comment: @klutt Meh. Maybe Sneftel could use it to edit their answer, which is essentially the same point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the next representable value after -0.0 is +0.0 ....

False premise.
`-0.0` and `+0.0` have the same *value*.
`if (-0.0 == +0.0)` is *true*.

`nextafter()` "functions determine the next representable **value**" (C17dr § 7.12.11.3 2)

`nextafter(-0.0, INFINITY)` and `nextafter(+0.0, INFINITY)` both return `DBL_TRUE_MIN`.

---

`+0.0` and `-0.0` often make no functional difference.  Sometimes they do make a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332133/what-operations-and-functions-on-0-0-and-0-0-give-different-arithmetic-results).

---

Advanced: Be prepared for C2X with expected decimal floating point support as there are many encoding sets of [decimal64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) that have the same *value*.  Repeated use of `nextafter()` and friends does not form a sequence through all FP encodings.

Comment: Ok, so for `-0.0` the _next representable value_ is not `+0.0`, because `+0.0` is the _same_ value, and not the _next_ value.

Comment: It is all about terminology. If `+0.0` is the same _value_ as `-0.0`, then will `+0.0` be the next _number_ after `-0.0`? I.e. in what terminology `+0.0` is different from `-0.0`?

Comment: @pmor Hmmm, sounds like you want some _sequence_ function.   Phrases like [_total-ordering predicate_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Total-ordering_predicate)  are more like `nextafter()`.  Perhaps [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349481/2410359) may help.

Comment: FYI: Just faced the case `a - b = c => b = a - c`, which fails to hold if `a` is `0.0` and `b` is `-0.0`. We have `0.0 - (-0.0) = 0.0 => b = 0.0 - 0.0 = 0.0`. The sign is lost. The `-0.0` is not recovered.

Answer (score 2):

Because +0 is not “after” -0, since it compares equal to -0.